# C setup file throwing error : is not an identifier

Tags: shell, makefile, ksh

I'm running a setup file to compile my C application on Linux (Red Hat) environment and getting below error:

```
+ . ../setup
+ G1ECHO='echo -e'
+ export $'G1ECHO\r'
/build_unix.sh[77]: .[2]: export: G1ECHO
: is not an identifier
```

Starting few lines of my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
APECHO="echo -e";                   export APECHO
APSYS="LINUX";                      export APSYS
APSYS_LOWERCASE="linux";                export APSYS_LOWERCASE
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64;             export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any input in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using a Makefile? Can you include it as well?

Comment: @NickODell I'm using make file but getting this error before running makefile.

Comment: I see - I don't get this error when running this ksh script. Can you add more information to allow others to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Looks like this script is being sourced by build_unix.sh, not executed, so the `#!` line will be ignored.  If the shell running build_unix.sh is *not* ksh, that may be an issue.  (In particular, csh would give an error like this)

Comment: export $'G1ECHO\r' .... this looks extremely suspicious, but based on what you've told us, we don't know where it came from. All we can say is, you can't export something starting with $...., you can only export an identifier.

Comment: The portion of the script presented does not appear to be the one that produces the output shown.    We really need to see a [mre] demonstrating the issue to be able to advise you about the specifics.

Comment: You have a file, somewhere, that uses `\r\n` line endings. `dos2unix` is your friend here.

Comment: @glennjackman - exactly the problem turns out to this. `dos2unix` command did worked.
Thank you!!